# Getting this error while insert 'System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements'

Tags: apex

I'm getting the following error 'System.ListException: Before Insert or Upsert list must not have two identically equal elements' when i'm trying below code

```
Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> parentQuoteLines = new Map<Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();

for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c  qli : qliToInsert){

if( String.isBlank(qli.SBQQ__RequiredBy__r.Id) 
                            && !parentQuoteLines .containsKey(qli.Id) 
   &&qliprodCodetoRecordMap.containsKey(qli.SBQQ__Product__c)){
                                parentQuoteLines.put(qli.Id,qliprodCodetoRecordMap.get(qli.SBQQ__Product__c));
                        }

if(!parentQuoteLines .values().isEmpty()){

    insert parentQuoteLines .values(); // Getting error when inserting
}
```

Comment: What does this map `qliprodCodetoRecordMap` stores? There is a possibility that same record has been added in map.

Comment: qliprodCodetoRecordMap it stores Quoteline fields related to that qli.id.

Comment: Below answer should solve your problem.

Comment: I guess code variables are confusing, so edited the code have a look.  Thanks Nitesh

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
parentProducts.put(qli.Id, qliprodCodetoRecordMap.get(qli.Id));
```

or this (more likely what you want):

```
parentProducts.put(qli.SBQQ__Product__c, qliprodCodetoRecordMap.get(qli.SBQQ__Product__c));
```

or this (cleaner code version):

```
SBQQ__QuoteLine__c pqli = qliprodCodetoRecordMap.get(qli.SBQQ__Product__c);
parentProducts.put(pqli.Id, pqli);
```

would avoid duplicate records but this *mixture* that you are using will not:

```
parentProducts.put(qli.Id, qliprodCodetoRecordMap.get(qli.SBQQ__Product__c));
```

Comment: i guess code variables are confusing, i have edited the code please have a look. thanks nitesh